# How to remove (hide) search box from All Posts in Wordpress admin?

Tags: wordpress

How can I remove the search box that appears in `edit.php` **without CSS**. I want to remove it from a certain Custom Post Type.
Is there any filter like below that hides the date filter dropdown?

```
add_filter('months_dropdown_results', '__return_empty_array');
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know you don't want to by CSS but you can use the body class of admin like for product custom post tye you can use `post-type-product` as parent class You can use `admin_footer` to add a custom CSS admin side. check below code. code goes in your active theme functions.php file.

```
function hide_search_box(){
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .post-type-product .search-box{ display:none } // only hide in product post type
    </style>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'hide_search_box', 10, 1 );
```